# how to add comments to website

Tags: php, html

In an effort to give a website im working on more functionality, im wanting the ability for readers to post comments/thoughts to the stories they read.

any ideas the best way to go about this?

ive tried Google but the minute i add the word "comments " + html or php etc (assuming i can do it in these languages) then google just gives me methods to commenting on code....

Any ideas, tips, tutorials etc ill gladly jump on.

Thanks in advance

-somdow

Comment: 1. database 2. script to accept comments and put them in the database. 3. script to retrieve comments and display them in the appropriate place. 4. scripts to manage comments so you can get rid of the inevitable comment spam you'll get flood with.  Beyond that, it's up to you.

Comment: If you want a robust commenting system, and are OK with a 3rd party hosting your comments, in exchange for managing identities, etc you may want to consider disqus.com.

Answer (score 6):

Well the most popular embeddable comment system is probably [Disqus](http://disqus.com/dashboard/). Besides that you will have to look if there are plugins for your framework of choice - or just roll your own (a comment system is basically just like any other database backed PHP application - and there are many ways to implement these).

Comment: +1.  Several sites are now using Disqus, and you don't have to manage or deal with user accounts/password/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just look at how popular content management systems have implemented comments? (For instance, take a look at how Drupal and Wordpress do it.) The manner in which you build a comment system will depend on your needs and the limitations imposed by the structure of the system you're trying to integrate it with.

Comment: To be honest, ive recently started learning php. im more of a dedicated front end guy, html css as3 etc. But the more i go into it the more i see avenues opening up to me. As far disqus. im looking now. thanks fellas...just trying to figure out if its free so i can test lol.

Answer (score 0):

You should work out your database schema first.  I'm assuming you're writing all of this from from scratch.  You haven't given a lot of details.

It will be easier if you put your comments in a separate table. Make sure you have some basic protections against bots(captcha, etc.)

Sort the results by the timestamp.

comments_table

- Id
- UserId
- UserDisplayName
- ArticleId
- Comment
- PostTime

Answer (score 0):

Disqus is nice, I must say. If you want code that you want to copy/paste, Google Friend Connect is a different route you can take... Almost everyone has a google account and it only takes a few minutes to set up. They also have some sweet other widgets you might want to try out like rating, etc.

[http://google.com/friendconnect](http://www.google.com/friendconnect/)

If you really want to customize it just how you want it, I would create your own commenting system with a MYSQL database to store all your data. You could even use some nice jQuery animations when they write / delete a comment. (I just did something simular to that and it's really nice).

Whatever works best for you -- roll with it!

Good luck,
Coulton

Comment: Thanks gentlemen!!! amazing stuff. as far as writing my own, if there isnt a tutorial somewhere, ill be copy/pasting lol. im TOO new to php so that wont be happening anytime soon unless its not as hard as i think it is lol. anyways, disqus is already up. i tested and its nice. i want to remove a few things like the disqus logo etc but since its free i assume i cant. ill try google friend next. again. Thanks for the info guys. much appreciated.